# Concatenating strings in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have declared the following strings in my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE= date +"%d.%m.%Y"
FILE_PREFIX="V_Articles_"
FILE_EXTENSION=".json"
```

I would like to combine these strings to generate a filename

```
echo "$FILE_PREFIX$DATE_$FILE_EXTENSION"
```

But no matter what I do, the date string would be printed on the first line and then the rest of the string would be printed on the second line.

Output:

```
01.10.2023
V_Articles_.json
```

If i try concatenating the strings like:
echo $FILE_PREFIX+$DATE+$FILE_EXTENSION"

I get the following output:

```
 01.10.2023
 V_Articles_++.json
```

How can I get the desired output where the date would be included?

Comment: You are assigning `DATE=` but then interpolating `$DATE_` with an underscore in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use command substitution $() for the date.  It allows you to execute a command and substitute its output in place of the $() expression

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y")
FILE_PREFIX="V_Articles_"
FILE_EXTENSION=".json"
echo "$FILE_PREFIX$DATE$FILE_EXTENSION"
```

Answer (score -1):

The result of the date command ends with \n (break line).
You can try this:

```bash
DATE= date +"[%d.%m.%Y]"|tr -d "\n"
FILE_PREFIX="V_Articles_"
FILE_EXTENSION=".json"

echo "$FILE_PREFIX$DATE_$FILE_EXTENSION"
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just prints out everything on the same line. And why are there square brackets added?